# What does the 'verb 'signify' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

In this following context, which meaning is suitable for the verb 'signify' according to two given definitions?

1. to be a sign of something; to mean;
2. to make something known; to show
   ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/))

Context:

> The word “cause” signifies only one of the many kinds of conditions,
> and it should, in Buddhist philosophy, be reserved for kamma, i.e. the
> rebirth-producing volitional activities bound up with wholesome or
> unwholesome roots (hetu), constituting the cause of rebirth, and
> resulting in rebirth as their effect, or vipåka.

Source: P. 31
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: It has more of a sense here of "represents", or "stands for".

Answer (score 0):

In the given context, the suitable meaning of the verb '**signify**' is **"to mean" or "to be a sign of something."** The sentence is explaining that the word "cause" has a specific meaning in Buddhist philosophy. It indicates that "cause" is used to refer to kamma, which is associated with volitional activities that lead to rebirth, according to your example.